# Firmarte a una pagina web usando macros

Tags: excel, macros, vb

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente:

Estoy creando una macros que me enlace a una pagina web.

```
Sub Reporte()

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "https://paginaweb.html"

End Sub
```

Veo la siguiente pagina web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando la macros tengo que igresar el usuarios y el contraseña para accesar al sitio.

Eso es posible de hacer usando macros ?

Comment: checa esto: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/461524-vba-open-website-logon-username-password.html

Comment: Sí, que es posible. Pero necesitamos saber el código fuente para ayudarte. Básicamente, se trata de jugar con el [Método HtmlDocument.GetElementById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) y similares, para seleccionar cada inputbox e introducir el usuario y contraseña, y luego seleccionar el button de Sign In y hacer click. Pero para ello, es necesario ver el código fuente